# Почему при запуске программы в android studio вылетает ошибка Unresolved reference: findByView

Tags: android, kotlin

Сам код после создания проекта, практически не менялся, добавил только те команды, которые говорили добавить в видео. На видео у лектора нужные места выделяются сами, становятся курсивом, а при написании команд выскакивает контекстное меню подсказок (которое предлагает как написать команду дальше). У меня всего этого нет и выскакивает ошибка. Плагины скачал все, которые нужны

```
package com.example.pract

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.enableEdgeToEdge
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val label = findByView<TextView>(R.id.main_label)
        val user_data : EditText = findViewById(R.id.user_data)
        val button : Button = findViewById(R.id.button)

        button.SetOnClickListener{
            val text = user_data.text.toString().trim()
            if(text == "toast")
                Toast.makeText(this, "User enter toast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Вы перепутали `findByView` с `findViewById`

Comment: Или `findViewByTag`

Answer (score 0):

Справка гугла на FindByView [ничего не находит](https://developer.android.com/s/results?q=findbyview). Следовательно, FindByView не существует.